# OpenCL double precision different from CPU double precision

Tags: opencl

I am programming in OpenCL using a GeForce GT 610 card in Linux. My CPU and GPU double precision results are not consistent. I can post part of the code here, but I would first like to know whether anyone else has faced this problem. The difference between the GPU and CPU double precision results get pronounced when I run loops with many iterations. There is really nothing special about the code, but I can post it here if anyone is interested. Thanks a lot. Here is my code. Please excuse the __ and bad formatting as I am new here :) As you can see, I have two loops and my CPU code is essentially almost an identical version.

```
#ifdef cl_khr_fp64
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#elif defined(cl_amd_fp64)
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_fp64 : enable
#else
#error "Double precision floating point not supported by OpenCL implementation."
```

#endif

```
__kernel void simpar(__global double* fp, __global double* fp1,
  __global double* fp3, __global double* fp5,
 __global double* fp6, __global double* fp7,
 __global double* fp8, __global double* fp8Plus,
 __global double* x, __global double* v, __global double* acc,
 __global double* keBuf, __global double* peBuf,
 unsigned int prntstps, unsigned int nprntstps, double dt
 ) {
unsigned int m,i,j,k,l,t;
unsigned int chainlngth=100;
double dxi, twodxi, dxipl1, dximn1, fac, fac1, fac2, fac13, fac23;
double ke,pe,tke,tpe,te,dx;
double hdt, hdt2;
double alpha=0.16;
double beta=0.7;
double cmass;
double peTemp;
nprntstps=1001;
dt=0.01;
prntstps=100;
double alphaby4=beta/4.0;
hdt=0.5*dt;
hdt2=dt*0.5*dt;
double Xlocal,Vlocal,Acclocal;
unsigned int global_id=get_global_id(0);
if (global_id<chainlngth){
Xlocal=x[global_id];
Vlocal=v[global_id];
Acclocal=acc[global_id];
for (m=0;m<nprntstps;m++){

for(l=0;l<prntstps;l++){
               Xlocal =Xlocal+dt *Vlocal+hdt2*Acclocal; 
               x[global_id]=Xlocal;
               barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

              Vlocal =Vlocal+ hdt * Acclocal; 
              barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

            j = global_id - 1;
            k = global_id + 1;
            if (j == -1) {
                    dximn1 = 0.0;
            } else {
                    dximn1 = x[j];
            }
            if (k == chainlngth) {
                    dxipl1 = 0.0;
            } else {
                    dxipl1 = x[k];
            }
            dxi = Xlocal;
            twodxi = 2.0 * dxi;
            fac = dxipl1 + dximn1 - twodxi;
            fac1 = dxipl1 - dxi;
            fac2 = dxi - dximn1;
            fac13 = fac1 * fac1 * fac1;
            fac23 = fac2 * fac2 * fac2;
            Acclocal = alpha * fac + beta * (fac13 - fac23);

            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

            Vlocal += hdt * Acclocal;
            v[global_id]=Vlocal;
            acc[global_id]=Acclocal;
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
       }
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

            tke = tpe = te = dx = 0.0;
            ke=0.5*Vlocal*Vlocal;//Vlocal*Vlocal;
           barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
            fp6[(m*100)+global_id]=ke;
            keBuf[global_id]=ke;
            ke=0.0; 
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);


            j = global_id - 1;
            k = global_id + 1;
            if (j == -1) {
                    dximn1 = 0.0;
            } else {
                    dximn1 = x[j];
            }
            if (k == chainlngth) {
                    dxipl1 = 0.0;
            } else {
                    dxipl1 = x[k];
            }
            dxi = Xlocal;
            twodxi = 2.0 * dxi;
            fac = dxipl1 + dximn1 - twodxi;
            fac1 = dxipl1 - dxi;
            fac2 = dxi - dximn1;
            fac13 = fac1 * fac1 * fac1;
            fac23 = fac2 * fac2 * fac2;
            Acclocal = alpha * fac + beta * (fac13 - fac23);

            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

            Vlocal += hdt * Acclocal;
            v[global_id]=Vlocal;
            acc[global_id]=Acclocal;
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
       }
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

            tke = tpe = te = dx = 0.0;
            ke=0.5*Vlocal*Vlocal;//Vlocal*Vlocal;
           barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
            fp6[(m*100)+global_id]=ke;
            keBuf[global_id]=ke;
            ke=0.0; 
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
            j = global_id - 1;
            k = global_id + 1;
            if (j == -1) {
                    dximn1 = 0.0;
            } else {
                    dximn1 = x[j];
            }
            if (k == chainlngth) {
                    dxipl1 = 0.0;
            } else {
                    dxipl1 = x[k];
            }
            dxi = Xlocal;
            twodxi = 2.0 * dxi;
            fac = dxipl1 + dximn1 - twodxi;
            fac1 = dxipl1 - dxi;
            fac2 = dxi - dximn1;
            fac13 = fac1 * fac1 * fac1;
            fac23 = fac2 * fac2 * fac2;
            Acclocal = alpha * fac + beta * (fac13 - fac23);

            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

            Vlocal += hdt * Acclocal;
            v[global_id]=Vlocal;
            acc[global_id]=Acclocal;
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
       }
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

            tke = tpe = te = dx = 0.0;
            ke=0.5*Vlocal*Vlocal;//Vlocal*Vlocal;
           barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
            fp6[(m*100)+global_id]=ke;
            keBuf[global_id]=ke;
            ke=0.0; 
            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
     if (global_id ==0){
             for(t=0;t<100;t++)
                  tke+=keBuf[t];
            }

            barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); 
            k = global_id-1;
            if (k == -1) {
                dx = Xlocal;
            }else{
              dx = Xlocal-x[k];
            }

              fac = dx * dx;
              peTemp = alpha * 0.5 * fac + alphaby4 * fac * fac;
              fp8[global_id*m]=peTemp;
              if (global_id == 0)
                    tpe+=peTemp;

              barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);  
              cmass=0.0;  
              dx = -x[100-1];
              fac = dx*dx;

              pe=alpha*0.5*fac+alphaby4*fac*fac;
              if (global_id==0){
              fp8Plus[m]=pe;
              tpe+=peBuf[0];
              fp5[m*2]=i;
              fp5[m*2+1]=cmass;
              te=tke+tpe;
              fp[m*2]=m;
              fp[m*2+1]=te;

             }
   barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
              //cmass /=100;
             fp1[(m*chainlngth)+global_id]=Xlocal-cmass; 
             // barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
              fp3[(m*chainlngth)+global_id]=Vlocal;
             // barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
             fp7[(m*chainlngth)+global_id]=Acclocal;

              barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
  }
 }
```

}

Comment: When you say "not consistent", what do you actually mean? Can you illustrate the differences quantitatively (absolute and relative errors, number of last place digits in agreement)?

Comment: I am executing the same (two) nested loops. The inner loop executes 100 times and then the outer loop prints some results. Here is a sample from the first iteration of the outer loop:

CPU: 0.0000000011
0.0000030832
0.0005244239
0.1400572807
1.5213598941
1.5213598941
0.1400572807
0.0005244239
0.0000030832
0.0000000011

GPU:
0.0000000012
0.0000032002
0.0005183133
0.1401775827
1.5249561626
1.5249561626
0.1401775827
0.0005183133
0.0000032002
0.0000000012

Comment: When you say "CPU double precision" do you mean executing the same kernel on the CPU device, or are you comparing against a native implementation? Also make sure you're not passing any flags to the OpenCL compiler which may relax IEEE strictness (e.g. enabling fast mul-add operations and so on). And yes the code would certainly help so that people can reproduce and do their own tests, without code the best we can do is speculate.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have written clearly. It is a native, single-threaded implementation on the CPU that I am comparing with.

Could you please specify which flag it could be? Is it while enqueuing the kernel? thanks

Comment: @Newbee That simplifies matters - OpenCL devices typically (unless specified otherwise) operate in strict conformance to the IEEE floating-point standard. CPU's (in native code) typically don't as they are often made to either use approximations to improve performance, or operate in 80-bit floating-point mode (the so-called "extended" mode) which as you can guess leads to more accurate results. To be completely accurate you would need to reset the CPU's floating-point state, which is a bit complicated. Try calling `_fpreset()` or some equivalent for your language/platform before native code.

Comment: (this is actually a big problem for a lot of applications, particularly networked software, which need to make sure all CPU's used are actually doing the same floating-point calculations, lest the results eventually diverge)

Comment: Thank you very much. So I can call _fpreset() from my C code at the very start? OK, I will read up. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Because you are not using any transcendental functions, it should be possible to make opencl and native cpu produce an exact match. If you can post a complete sample code for both opencl and native execution, I could debug it. I have only AMD gpu and not nvidia gpu though.

Comment: @ScottD, thanks a lot for your offer. However, since we have different GPUs, it may be difficult to match it on nVidia GPUs. On a different note, can anyone tell me how to use _fpreset() from gcc? I could not find any information and couldn't figure out the correct include file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is somewhat expected behavior, actually.

On older x86 CPUs, floating point numbers are 80bits long (Intel's ["long double"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double)), and truncated to 64bit only when need be.
When SIMD units/instructions for floating point arithmetics arrived for x86 CPUs, floating point double precision became 64bit by default; however, 80bit is still possible, depending on your compiler settings. There's a lot to read about this out there: [Wikipedia: Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Check your compiler settings for OpenCL **and** host code on floating point "magic tricks", to get better agreement of your results. Calculate the [absolute](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteError.html) and [relative error](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeError.html) of your values and check if this error margin is safe for your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the "-ffloat-store" option with gcc, there is no difference. Could you please suggest any other compiler option for gcc that could make it follow strict IEEE standards?

Comment: @Newbee Summary of gcc options releated to floating point precision: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Comment: Try **-funsafe-math-optimizations -O3** for the "worst case", and work your way down to **-O0**. Additionally, check the options for the **-mfpmath=unit** switch, and the **-m___** switches for code generation for different units. My **guess** is that the OpenCL code is heavily optimized, so enabling "unsafe" optimizations should get your CPU results closer to the OpenCL results.